# Copy and Paste Password for Comments

Tags: comments, forms, password

One of my newer clients has an extensive WordPress blog (on SE I am a Joomla man) and I am sure there must be some reason behind this.

**For comments it asks you to copy a password - and then paste it!**

I can't not figure out if this is a feature of WordPress which is being misused (obviously not meant to be) or a rouge web designer who has simple created something very odd indeed.

Although the client is fairly well clued up there is no explanation for this from his end other than "don't know".

[image]

Edit: Is this a incredibly poorly thought out Capatcha alternative?

Comment: What **Theme** is active? What **Plugins** are active? The functionality you describe is not part of WordPress core, so it must be coming from the Theme or a Plugin.

Comment: The theme is thesis_184 and no plugins :/

Comment: No Plugins - at all? That's highly unusual. But, if Thesis is adding the functionality, you'll need to check with DIYThemes support; as it's a commercial Theme, we don't have access to the codebase.

Comment: This makes no sense. My vote: "a rouge web designer who has simple created something very odd indeed" o_0

Answer (score 1):

That is not a feature of WordPress.

I have seen that particular wording before though. It is added by the "Spam Free WordPress" plugin.

And yes, it's not a great way to go. For spam prevention, I recommend using these plugins instead:

- Akismet
- Cookies for Comments
- Simple Trackback Validation

Comment: Perfect thank you. It is an awful way to go - no idea why web designer x thought it was a good idea. Have to leave it for the time being; out of my domain of control but won't be there a second longer than need be!